# Internet explorer consumes more and more RAM for every refresh

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, ram

I have just started working with an application that for every time I refresh the start page it increases the memory consumption by 3-4 Mb. I have done some analysis with sIEve (http://home.wanadoo.nl/jsrosman/) and found a lot of memory leaks. But I have seen other websites (i e facebook) with the same number of leaks that does not increase in memory as rapid as this application. Can there be other reasons for this behaviour?

Does anyone have any tips on what to start with, any other tools e t c to find the worst leaks or causes of memory escalation?

Comment: Check out [dynaTrace Ajax Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE?  IE8 is supposed to be better at handling memory leaks.
You can memory leaks that hang around even after a refresh.
There are lots of examples you can find.   Usually you can recoup some memory after a page refresh, but there are some cases (I believe with plugins) where memory is not completely recovered.  Gradually it gets worse and worse until you close the browser.

But like I said - IE8 was supposed to have solved some of this.

IE8 can still have memory leaks.  Something to do with the DOM.  If you have a complex jQuery application doing a lot of DOM work and the page never refreshes (i.e., the application is a single page using AJAX) you can see the memory go up and up even though you think you are clearing things out properly.

Moral of the story:  IE sucks.

Comment: Its IE8, but I cant really see a huge difference between IE7 and IE8 (and even 9) in this case. The JS-code is very poorly written but Where to start??